# Rails Paperclip image upload not working on mobile

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, paperclip, mobile-browser, paperclip-validation

I'm creating a site that allows users to upload images from their mobile phones, through their browser. Before adding this feature to my site, I'm testing it out with a rails scaffold. To accomplish image upload, I'm using Paperclip 4.1. Image uploading is working flawlessly on my laptop, but it isn't working on my Android. When I click "Choose file" on my droid, I am able to select an image from my galley (among many other options), but when I click "Update" I get two errors:

```
Avatar content type is invalid
Avatar is invalid
```

The content type is a jpg, which I know is valid because I can upload jpgs on my laptop. I don't understand what the other error means. Here is the validation I'm using (got it from paperclip's quick start guide on GitHub):

```
validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
```

Is this a flaw of paperclip, or am I doing something wrong? Please let me know if you need more of my code.

Comment: can you post the API code that you use to upload the image?

Comment: I'm not using any APIs, just the Paperclip gem. Is there an API I'm supposed to be using?

Comment: Are you working for android app or trying to upload image through  mobile browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using CarrierWave instead, which was able to handle image uploads through mobile and desktop.